# PhpStorm: issue in connecting SSH through SFTP getting "Algorithm negotiation fail" in Mac Sierra

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Facing issue in connecting with SFTP/SSH
Operating System : Mac Sierra
PhpStorm Version : 8.0.4

> 2017-06-26 16:48:58,697 [  21927]  DEBUG - emoteRunConfiguration$Settings - Format error: no binding for [Attribute: factoryName="PHPUnit on Server"] inside BeanBinding[com.jetbrains.php.run.deploymentAware.phpunit.PhpUnitRemoteRunConfiguration$Settings, tagName=Settings]
>
> 2017-06-26 16:48:58,959 [  22189]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 123 project components initialized in 579 ms
>
> 2017-06-26 16:48:58,984 [  22214]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 1 module(s) loaded in 24 ms
>
> 2017-06-26 16:48:59,055 [  22285]   INFO - om.intellij.util.ProfilingUtil - Profiling agent is not enabled. Add -agentlib:yjpagent to idea.vmoptions if necessary to profile IDEA.
>
> 2017-06-26 16:49:00,127 [  23357]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342
>
> 2017-06-26 16:49:00,953 [  24183]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 917 ms
>
> 2017-06-26 16:49:02,294 [  25524]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 3961 ms
>
> 2017-06-26 16:49:02,475 [  25705]  ERROR - jediterm.terminal.TerminalMode - Mode EightBitInput is not implemented, setting to true
>
> 2017-06-26 16:49:40,101 [  63331]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [com.jetbrains.php, com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment]

Above is the log and I also tried some workaround to make this work but no luck, I have added the additional code mentioned below in **sshd_config** file

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try the solution from comments section: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206708679-FTPS-connection-error-not-secure-Ciphers

Comment: PhpStorm **v8**? It's an old version -- try downloading latest 2017.1.4 and try the same there.

Comment: @Edwin I tried the solution as mentioned in  that post, but no luck its not working.

Comment: @LazyOne I want to run on this version

Comment: My point is: the server may use protocols/ciphers that PhpStorm v8 (which is 2.5 years old now) may simply not support. In such case solution _might be_ in weakening supported protocols/ciphers on the server side. I have only suggested you to **try** 2017.1 version to check if that simply works there.

Comment: @LazyOne yea will update the IDE  and I will check. That might help.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) First Install Java SE JDK:
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
>
> 2.) Then download the .exe version (or .dmg). Run and install it in your computer
>
> 3.) Then download: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
>
> 4.) Then go to the directory (for Windows - C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 9.0.3\jre\jre\lib\security - for MAC - /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib ) AND replace "local_policy" and "US_export_policy" with the new ones you just download
>
> It should run smoothly now
> Uninstall all the versions and start from scratch before you do this to have a clean start.

Comment: It worked! I have replaced files in both folders: (1) C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.2.4\jre64\lib\security\policy\limited (2) C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.2.4\jre64\lib\security\policy\unlimited

Comment: @FaisalAlvi Great, Happy coding.  Accept my answer as a solution so that others can also refer to this.